# Price list CSV import locale issue

Tags: locale, intershop

In IS version 7.10.38.9-LTS price list import converter has hardcoded US locale value for name and description fields.

Resulting backend for German language looks:
[image]

Is this issue meant to be localized in future versions?
So that we can choose option to adapt either CSV files or override/create own converter template.

PriceListCSVConvert.isml:

```
<description xml:lang="en-US"><isif condition="#isDefined(data:PriceList_Description)#"><isprint value="#data:PriceList_Description#"></isif></description>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bringing this issue to our attention.
A bug ticket has been created, and we will evaluate it later this week.

As far as I know, it has been like this for a very long time and we never heard about issues with it.
If I interpret the other csv templates correctly, it is only possible to import an attribute (for example price list description) in exactly one locale and you would like this locale to be customizable, is that correct?

Comment: That's correct, currently import of fields name and description are only imported on English. For example, product has fields for locale, NameLang, LongDescriptionLang and ShortDescriptionLang to support localization.